# HTML,PHP - Escape '<' and '>' symbols while echoing

Tags: php, html, escaping

I want to print following text as it is:

```
echo "<label> AAAAA";
```

But  it is just showing 'AAAAA' as output.

How can I escape '<' and '>' symbol.

Comment: `<pre>` wouldn't escape them anyway. It just makes white space significant.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars("abc & < >");
?>
```

Comment: It's annoying that the `htmlspecialchars` function is not succintly named. I wish PHP had an equivalent of ASP.NET's `<%: expr %>` or Razor's `@( expr )` which _automatically_ HTML-encodes the text to be rendered. In all of my PHP projects I alias `htmlentities( expr )` as `E( expr )` so I can have `<?= E( expr ) ?>`. Given PHP's "everything and the kitchen-sink" feature-set it's surprising it doesn't have an auto-encode feature or syntax built-in already. And correct HTML encoding is very important to prevent XSS attacks and should be encouraged.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    $string = "<label> AAAAA"; //whatever you want
    echo htmlspecialchars($string);
?>
```

**refrence** [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to convert into a plain text string.

```
<?php
echo htmlentities("<label> AAAAA");
?>
```

Comment: htmlentities is overkill. No need to bloat output by converting characters that are better represented with regular characters.

Comment: The only time I'd consider `htmlentities` better than `htmlspecialchars` would be if the output is in a different charset than the code, which normally isn't the case.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo htmlentities("<label> AAAAA");
```

Answer (score 3):

check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php, and this is code -

```
echo htmlentities ("<label> AAAAA");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should escape your especial characters for HTML.

`echo "&lt;label&gt; AAAA"`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: +1 for the right answer, but -1 for referring to w3schools. There are much better resources out there for learning this kind of stuff. (you may want to read http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "&lt;label&gt; AAAAA";
```

Comment: And it usually makes more sense to do this in an automated way.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML entities: `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`. Could be achieved using `htmlspecialchars` function: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars.

Read more about HTML entities here: http://www.santagata.us/characters/CharacterEntities.html