# preg_match returns an empty string even there is a match

Tags: php, arrays, tags, preg-match-all

I am trying to extract all meta tags in web page, currently am using preg_match_all to get that, but unfortunately it returns an empty strings for the array indexes.

```
 <?php
  $meta_tag_pattern = '/<meta(?:"[^"]*"[\'"]*|\'[^\']*\'[\'"]*|[^\'">])+>/';
  $meta_url = file_get_contents('test.html');
  if(preg_match_all($meta_tag_pattern, $meta_url, $matches) == 1)
    echo "there is a match <br>";

  print_r($matches);
?>
```

Returned array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) )
```

Comment: Since `preg_match_all` returns the number of matches, I suggest you to write only: `if(preg_match_all($meta_tag_pattern, $meta_url, $matches) )` or to use `preg_match` if you are looking for the first result.

Comment: It is more easy to use DOMDocument to obtain the result you want.

Comment: Here's how I'd capture meta tags /<meta\s[^>]+>/ . What do you want to capture? The whole tag? The attributes? The attribute values?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I thought it may be a logic error in my code, so I tried other methods to `write` if statement. Am looking for a performance way to parse the page, that it way I didn't use `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles It returns empty strings too, I want to capture the whole tag.

Comment: I understand, building the DOM Tree has a cost, but once it is done, the queries are fast. And don't forget that a regex has a cost too.

Comment: add `i` flag i.e. case insensitive. Check the source html code to ensure your code from `print_r` not been parsed as HTML code by browser.

Comment: @Deadooshka You were right, it turns out that `print_r` outputs rendered as `html` by the browser, to avoid that I Googled and found this snippets: 
`function print_html_r($var) {
  ob_start();
  print_r($var);
  $contents = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  print htmlentities($contents);
}`
Would you re-post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Example grabbing meta tags from URL:

```
$meta_tag_pattern = '/<meta\s[^>]+>/';
$meta_url = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551116/html-php-escape-and-symbols-while-echoing');
if(preg_match_all($meta_tag_pattern, $meta_url, $matches))
  echo "there is a match <br>";

foreach ( $matches[0] as $value ) {
    print htmlentities($value) . '<br>';
}
```

Outputs:

```
there is a match 
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
<meta name="og:type" content="website" />
...
```

Looks like part of the problem is the browser rendering the meta tags as meta tags and not displaying the text when you print_r the output, so they need to be escaped.

Comment: Whould you try to extract the `meta` tag of [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812216/preg-match-returns-an-empty-string-even-there-is-a-match/) page as an example.

Comment: The `print_r` outputs was rendered as `html` by the browser I looked at by viewing the page source, that is why I didn't see the outputs and thought it as empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

An example with DOMDocument:

```
$url = 'test.html';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML($meta));
}
```

Comment: @JakeGould: Yes, however using `preg_match_all` for the same task with a good pattern and a not too badly formatted html is 100x faster.