# How to disable HTML effect in a tag but not the HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

While making a post feature with PHP , i realized that anyone can post their text with a tag also. For ex. `<b> What's Up</b>` or even `<marquee>Look, moving</marquee>` . When these types of data will be printed it would affect inside the post. Like `<b>` will make the post bold. There must a html `tag` or a way with `PHP` or `Javascript` to disable html inside a tag. 
I'm well aware of `strip_tags()`, but this function strips the tags for ex. `<b>blah blah</b>` will be shown like `blah blah` but i want it to be shown `<b> blah blah<b>` but not the `HTML` effect it would cause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML,PHP - Escape '<' and '>' symbols while echoing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551116/html-php-escape-and-symbols-while-echoing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [strip-tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.
Something like:

```
<?php
strip_tags($content, '');
?>
```

The second parameter is for allowed tags.

To show the html but not run it use `<pre>` tags and `CDATA`:

```
<pre><![CDATA[
<b>Blah Blah</b>
]]></pre>
```

Unfortunately, this only works for `XHTML` and `XML`.

Another alternative. and probably the most viable, is `<xmp>`: http://jsfiddle.net/8yfghmL9/

Comment: look again, i have edited the question.

Comment: 1) Is it necessary to use `<pre>` tag with `<![CDATA[  ]>`  2)is `<xmp>` more compatible ? 3) Does `<xmp>` has it's own style, like `<h1>` or `<p>` tags does.

Comment: Using `<pre>` tags in certain browsers is necessary. However this still works only with `XHTML`. `<xmp>` however is supported in most modern browsers. So, yes, I would go with `<xmp>`.

Comment: 3) Does <xmp> has it's own style, like <h1> or <p> tags does ?

Comment: No. It's basic text. You can enclose it all in a `div` and style it anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<?php
    echo strip_tags("Hello <b>world!</b>"); 
?>
```

this will strip the tags.. and give you pure text ...