# PHP Mysql - Echo HTML tags stored in a DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

first question here, my problem is this.

I've got 22 more or less values to print stored inside a table in a DB. Problem is some of this values gotta have HTML tags in it, mainly tags `<s>` .

```
<?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM teams";
                        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "
                    <div class='col-md-12'>
                        <div class='card strpied-tabled-with-hover'>
                            <div class='card-header '>
                                <h4 class='card-title'>".$row['name']." ".$row['surname']."</h4>
                                <p class='card-category'>".$row['team']."</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='card-body table-full-width table-responsive'>
                                <table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Player</th>
                                        <th>Player Bonus</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>".$row['c1']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c1b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c2']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c2b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c3']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c3b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>4</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c4']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c4b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>5</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c5']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c5b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>6</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c6']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c6b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>7</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c7']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c7b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>8</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c8']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c8b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>9</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c9']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c9b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>10</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c10']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c10b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>11</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c11']."</td>
                                            <td>".$row['c11b']."</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>";} ?>
```

TL;DR: $row[c1] and so on have HTML tags stored as values like `<s>stringvalue</s>` but it just echo `stringvalue`. What can I do? Thanks and sorry for my inexperience.

EDIT: I mispelled the title in an horrific way.

Comment: Could you please show us the output of this? It's difficult to understand your question

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: You can use htmlspecialchars like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551116/html-php-escape-and-symbols-while-echoing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the fast response of all of you, appreciate that. I tried to use htmlspecialchars and html_entity_decode but no luck. I'll try to express better by the way: i'd like to output a 
formatted barred <s>string</s> but instead I get just string.

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa